# How do I get data from a JSON file instead of CSV on my map?

Tags: csv, json

I am trying to display my API link that is in JSON instead of use DataCenters.csv, UtilityCloud.csv and VES_Sites.csv.

How can I do this? Is there any documentation that anyone knows about that can help me? It looks like this code is set up for CSV files only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<title>CDS Data Centers</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  html, body, 
  #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #search {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 20px;
    left: 74px;
  }
  #HomeButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 50;
  body {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  }
</style>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>
<script>
  var map, csv;
  require([
    "esri/map", "esri/dijit/Search", "esri/layers/CSVLayer",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/layers/LabelClass", "esri/symbols/TextSymbol", 
    "esri/Color", "esri/symbols/Font", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
    "esri/renderers/UniqueValueRenderer", "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/dijit/BasemapGallery",
    "esri/dijit/Basemap", "esri/dijit/BasemapLayer", "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
    "esri/dijit/HomeButton", "dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/TitlePane", "dojo/domReady!" 
  ], function(
    Map, Search, CSVLayer, FeatureLayer, LabelClass, TextSymbol, Color, Font, 
    SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleRenderer, 
    UniqueValueRenderer, InfoTemplate, BasemapGallery, Basemap, BasemapLayer, 
    Scalebar, HomeButton, parser
  ){
    parser.parse();
    var map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "satellite",
      center: [ 0,0 ],
      zoom: 2,
      showLabels: false
    });
    var scalebar = new Scalebar({
      map: map,
      scalebarUnit: "dual"
    });
    var home = new HomeButton({
      map: map
    }, "HomeButton");
    home.startup();
    var basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
      showArcGISBasemaps: true,
      map: map
    }, "basemapGallery");
    basemapGallery.startup();
    basemapGallery.on("error", function(msg) {
      console.log("basemap gallery error: ", msg);
    });
    var search = new Search({
      map: map
    }, "search");
    search.startup();

    var csv = new CSVLayer("./Data/DataCenters.csv", {
      outFields: ["*"]
    });
    var csv1 = new CSVLayer("./Data/VES_Sites.csv", {
      outFields: ["*"]
    });

    var labelSymbol = new TextSymbol().setColor(new Color([0, 63, 125, 0.9])).setFont(new Font("11px", Font.STYLE_NORMAL, Font.VARIANT_NORMAL, Font.WEIGHT_BOLD, "Century")).setOffset(0, 0).setAlign(TextSymbol.ALIGN_START).setHaloColor(new Color([255, 255, 255])).setHaloSize(1);
    var labelRenderer = new SimpleRenderer(labelSymbol);
    var json = {
      "labelExpressionInfo": {"value": "{Name}"},
      "labelPlacement":"above-center"
      };
    var lc = new LabelClass(json);
    lc.symbol = labelSymbol;
    csv.setLabelingInfo([ lc ]);

    var labelSymbol1 = new TextSymbol().setColor(new Color([0, 63, 125, 0.9])).setFont(new Font("8px", Font.STYLE_NORMAL, Font.VARIANT_NORMAL, Font.WEIGHT_BOLD, "Century")).setOffset(0, 0).setAlign(TextSymbol.ALIGN_START).setHaloColor(new Color([255, 255, 255])).setHaloSize(1);
    var labelRenderer1 = new SimpleRenderer(labelSymbol1);
    var json1 = {
      "labelExpressionInfo": {"value": "{Name}"},
      "labelPlacement":"below-center"
      };
    var lc1 = new LabelClass(json1);
    lc1.symbol = labelSymbol1;
    <!--csv1.setLabelingInfo([ lc1 ]);-->

    var defaultSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 15,
                          new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHED), 
                          new Color([76, 230, 0, 1]),
                          new Color([255, 255, 255, 0.7]));
    var renderer = new UniqueValueRenderer(defaultSymbol, "Status");
    renderer.addValue("Offline", new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 15,
                       new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHED), 
                       new Color([128, 128, 128, 0.7]),
                       new Color([255, 255, 255, 0.9])));

    var defaultSymbol1 = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 10,
                           new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                           new Color([32, 32, 32]), 0.7), 
                           new Color([0, 128, 255, 0.5]));
    var renderer1 = new UniqueValueRenderer(defaultSymbol1, "Status", "Facility_Type", null, ":");
    renderer1.addValue("Online:VES", new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 10,
                        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                        new Color([255, 255, 255]), 0.7), 
                        new Color([0, 169, 230, 0.5])));
    renderer1.addValue("Online:NEBS", new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 10,
                        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                        new Color([0, 169, 230]), 0.9), 
                        new Color([0, 169, 230, 0.7])));
    renderer1.addValue("Offline:VES", new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 10,
                        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                        new Color([255, 255, 255]), 0.9), 
                        new Color([130, 130, 130, 0.7])));
    renderer1.addValue("Offline:NEBS", new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 10,
                        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                        new Color([255, 0, 0]), 0.9), 
                        new Color([0, 169, 230, 0.7])));

    csv.setRenderer(renderer);
    csv1.setRenderer(renderer1);

    var template = new InfoTemplate();
    template.setTitle("${Name}");
    template.setContent("Status: ${Status}</br>Total CPU (VCPU): ${Total CPU}</br>Total Network: ${Total Network}</br>Total Storage (GB): ${Total Storage}</br></br><a target='_blank' href= http://txslnno-rhsat.cds.eng.vzwcorp.com/pub/vcp/index.html?data_group=${data_group}&site=${lname}>State0</a></br><a target='_blank' href= http://alerts.vcp.mon.vzwops.com/icingaweb2/monitoring/tactical/>Fault Tolerance</a></br><a target='_blank' href='http://10.75.140.109:3000/' style=\"display:none\" />Performance Metrics</a></br><a target='_blank' href='http://analytics.vcp.mon.vzwops.com:443/app/kibana#/discover' />Log Management</a>");

    var template_ves = new InfoTemplate();
    template_ves.setTitle("${Name} - ${Region}");
    template_ves.setContent("Status: ${Date}</br>Total CPU (VCPU): ${Total CPU}</br>Total Network: ${Total Network}</br>Total Storage (GB): ${Total Storage}</br></br><a target='_blank' href= http://txslnno-rhsat.cds.eng.vzwcorp.com/pub/vcp/index.html?data_group=${data_group}&site=${lname}>State0</a></br><a target='_blank' href= http://alerts.vcp.mon.vzwops.com/icingaweb2/monitoring/tactical/>Fault Tolerance</a></br><a target='_blank' href='http://10.75.140.109:3000/' style=\"display:none\" />Performance Metrics</a></br><a target='_blank' href='http://analytics.vcp.mon.vzwops.com:443/app/kibana#/discover' />Log Management</a>");

    csv.setInfoTemplate(template);
    csv1.setInfoTemplate(template_ves);

    map.addLayers([csv, csv1]);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what software is your map in?

Comment: if you have a script that can only accept csv as input, you have two options: 1. re-write the script to accept json as input; or 2. convert the json to csv (there are many free online converters)